# Not able tio install WebdriverIO Cucumber JS framework on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io, cucumberjs, node-fibers

npm install wdio-cucumber-framework --save-devfails with this error. same happens for wdio-mocha-framework.Looks like something wrong with node fibers.

> fibers@1.0.15 install C:\src\webdriverio-browserstack\node_modules\fibers
>   node build.js || nodejs build.js

```
C:\src\webdriverio-browserstack\node_modules\fibers>if not defined npm_config_no
de_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\n
ode_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node  rebuild -
-release )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:116:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\configure.js:71:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--rel
ease"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\src\webdriverio-browserstack\node_modules\fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v5.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup you
r
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
webdriverio-browserstack@0.1.0 C:\src\webdriverio-browserstack
└─┬ webdriverio@4.2.16
  └─┬ wdio-dot-reporter@0.0.6
    └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.38
      └── core-js@1.2.7

npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON webdriverio-browserstack@0.1.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "wdio-cucumber-framework" "--save-
dev"
npm ERR! node v5.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.15 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.15 install script 'node build.js || nodejs bui
ld.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build.js || nodejs build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed after upgrading to Node v6.8.0